# Error loading library gpuarray with Theano

Tags: gpu, theano

I am trying to run [this script](http://deeplearning.net/software/theano/tutorial/using_gpu.html#returning-a-handle-to-device-allocated-data) to test Theano's use of my GPU and get the following error:

```
ERROR (theano.gpuarray): Could not initialize pygpu, support disabled
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/me/anaconda3/envs/py35/lib/python3.5/site-
packages/theano/gpuarray/__init__.py", line 164, in <module>
    use(config.device)
  File "/home/me/anaconda3/envs/py35/lib/python3.5/site-
packages/theano/gpuarray/__init__.py", line 151, in use
    init_dev(device)
  File "/home/me/anaconda3/envs/py35/lib/python3.5/site-
packages/theano/gpuarray/__init__.py", line 60, in init_dev
    sched=config.gpuarray.sched)
  File "pygpu/gpuarray.pyx", line 614, in pygpu.gpuarray.init 
(pygpu/gpuarray.c:9419)
  File "pygpu/gpuarray.pyx", line 566, in pygpu.gpuarray.pygpu_init 
(pygpu/gpuarray.c:9110)
  File "pygpu/gpuarray.pyx", line 1021, in 
    pygpu.gpuarray.GpuContext.__cinit__ (pygpu/gpuarray.c:13472)
pygpu.gpuarray.GpuArrayException: Error loading library: -1
```

I need to use the `nvidia-381` driver since my GPU is a 1080 ti and is not compatible with `nvidia-375`.  I'm not sure if that matters but installing nvcc overwrites 381 and causes some errors if I reinstall 381 after setting up `nvcc` so I can't use `nvcc`.

I can import `pygpu` without errors but if I run `pygpu.test()` I get the following error and I don't know how to specify the `DEVICE` variable without `nvcc`.

```
======================================================================
ERROR: Failure: RuntimeError (No test device specified.  Specify one using the DEVICE or GPUARRAY_TEST_DEVICE environment variables.)
----------------------------------------------------------------------
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/me/anaconda3/envs/py35/lib/python3.5/site-packages/nose/failure.py", line 39, in runTest
    raise self.exc_val.with_traceback(self.tb)
  File "/home/me/anaconda3/envs/py35/lib/python3.5/site-packages/nose/loader.py", line 418, in loadTestsFromName
    addr.filename, addr.module)
  File "/home/me/anaconda3/envs/py35/lib/python3.5/site-packages/nose/importer.py", line 47, in importFromPath
    return self.importFromDir(dir_path, fqname)
  File "/home/me/anaconda3/envs/py35/lib/python3.5/site-packages/nose/importer.py", line 94, in importFromDir
    mod = load_module(part_fqname, fh, filename, desc)
  File "/home/me/anaconda3/envs/py35/lib/python3.5/imp.py", line 234, in load_module
    return load_source(name, filename, file)
  File "/home/me/anaconda3/envs/py35/lib/python3.5/imp.py", line 172, in load_source
    module = _load(spec)
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 693, in _load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 673, in _load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 665, in exec_module
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 222, in _call_with_frames_removed
  File "/home/me/.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/pygpu-0.6.2-py3.5-linux-x86_64.egg/pygpu/tests/test_tools.py", line 5, in <module>
    from .support import (guard_devsup, rand, check_flags, check_meta, check_all,
  File "/home/me/.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/pygpu-0.6.2-py3.5-linux-x86_64.egg/pygpu/tests/support.py", line 32, in <module>
    context = gpuarray.init(get_env_dev())
  File "/home/me/.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/pygpu-0.6.2-py3.5-linux-x86_64.egg/pygpu/tests/support.py", line 29, in get_env_dev
    raise RuntimeError("No test device specified.  Specify one using the DEVICE or GPUARRAY_TEST_DEVICE environment variables.")
RuntimeError: No test device specified.  Specify one using the DEVICE or GPUARRAY_TEST_DEVICE environment variables.

----------------------------------------------------------------------
Ran 7 tests in 0.003s

FAILED (errors=7)
<nose.result.TextTestResult run=7 errors=7 failures=0>
```

Comment: When this happens, it may be because pygpu cannot find the right version of Cuda. I believe pygpu versions 0.6.2 up to 0.6.4 look for Cuda 7.5, while those above 0.6.8 work with Cuda 8.0

Answer (score 3):

**Warning:** its entirely possible that this is all wrong and the actual reason for your problem is in fact - as you suspect - your gpu driver.

---

I had the same issue with gpuarray on Windows 10.
In the end I solved it by:

1. completely uninstall python
2. install cuda 8.0 (with cudnn 5.1)
3. install anaconda
4. install theano through anaconda:

   ```
   conda install theano pygpu
   ```

As you are using linux: This error message basically means *It didn't work, don't ask me why* And is mostly shown if something with your setup is wrong (e.g. different compilers used for compiling python and theano, or incompatible cuda version)

I would recommend to update to cuda 8.0 and to reinstall your python environment over anaconda (just in case)

On a side note: I tested your example script from the docu and at least that is working....

---

**Note for windows users:** Never try to install Anaconda in a location where you have spaces in the path... Everything looks fine ... until theano starts having trouble finding and compiling things.

---

Note regarding the `pygpu.test()`:

Normally you just set the environment variable:

```
windows: set DEVICE=cuda
linux: export DEVICE=cuda
```

**BUT** The test has the habit of saying you didn't specify a device if the library couldn't be loaded...

Comment: This did end up having to do with my driver.  `libcuda.so.1` doesn't exist with `nvidia-381` but installing `nvidia-378` got me the file and remained compatible with my GPU.  Thank you for taking the time to write this out though!

Comment: I'm going to just let it be there. There aren't many google results for  `pygpu.gpuarray.GpuArrayException: Error loading library: -1` maybe someone looking for a solution happens to find this post.

Comment: Makes sense to me.  Very likely it solves somebody's problem.

Comment: Just pinged the google crawler: https://www.google.de/search?safe=off&q="GpuArrayException%3A+Error+loading+library%3A"+%5C-1 4th entry, looks good to me (well 4th from 5 in total)

Comment: @FabianN.: I also come across such problem, even after I reinstall anaconda and theano and update cuda to 8.0 (you can see my post here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44346349/error-theano-gpuarray-could-not-initialize-pygpu-support-disabled). Without .theanorc file for configuration to use gpu, theano can be imported successfully. After you install theano, have you done something else, like installing other packages? Can you be more specific about your .theanorc file and some relate configuration? Thanks!!

Comment: You state that you are using cuda 8.0 but your root path points to v7.5...?