# ERROR (theano.gpuarray): Could not initialize pygpu, support disabled

Tags: gpu, theano

I am trying to configure theano 0.9 to use gpu, but got such error. 
I use windows 10 with nvidia GeForce 940m and cuda 8. Previously my system works fine with theano 0.8 for gpu computation. I just updated the theano.

```
 ERROR (theano.gpuarray): Could not initialize pygpu, support disabled
 Traceback (most recent call last):
 File "C:\Users\YL\Anaconda2\lib\site- packages\theano\gpuarray\__init__.py",   
 line 175, in <module>
use(config.device)
File "C:\Users\YL\Anaconda2\lib\site-packages\theano\gpuarray\__init__.py", line 162, in use
init_dev(device, preallocate=preallocate)
File "C:\Users\YL\Anaconda2\lib\site-packages\theano\gpuarray\__init__.py", line 65, in init_dev
sched=config.gpuarray.sched)
File "pygpu\gpuarray.pyx", line 614, in pygpu.gpuarray.init (pygpu/gpuarray.c:9415)
File "pygpu\gpuarray.pyx", line 566, in pygpu.gpuarray.pygpu_init (pygpu/gpuarray.c:9106)
File "pygpu\gpuarray.pyx", line 1021, in pygpu.gpuarray.GpuContext.__cinit__ (pygpu/gpuarray.c:13468)
GpuArrayException: Error loading library: -1
```

Without gpu configuration, theano works fine, otherwise it produces the error. I think I must do something wrong with the configuration. My .theanorc file is as follows:

```
[global]
device = cuda
floatX = float32

[cuda]
root = C:\Program Files\NVIDIA GPU Computing Toolkit\CUDA\v7.5

[nvcc]
fastmath = True
```

Comment: try setting `device=cuda0`, or have a look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43577788/error-loading-library-gpuarray-with-theano

Comment: @K_Augus: I tried many possibilities but still cannot resolve this issue

Comment: You state that you are using cuda 8.0 but your root path points to v7.5...?

Answer (score 0):

I am getting the same (similar) error when I run Theano code. I'm using a laptop with two gpu's (optimus technology). What fixed it for me is to run my python code with enabled gpu like so:
`optirun python2 my_code.py`
Hope this helps.