# "pygpu.gpuarray.GpuArrayException: b'Could not load "nvrtc64_70.dll": The specified module could not be found.\r\n'" error

Tags: python, gpu, nvidia, theano

I have a problem with theano when I want to use GPU. I create .theano.txt file and set device=cuda and floatX=float32. but when I run my python code and print "theano.config.device" I face with these errors.

```
WARNING (theano.tensor.blas): Using NumPy C-API based implementation for BLAS functions.
ERROR (theano.gpuarray): Could not initialize pygpu, support disabled
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "f:\Projects\Python\Environments\theano_env\lib\site-packages\theano\gpuarray\__init__.py", line 227, in <module>
    use(config.device)
  File "f:\Projects\Python\Environments\theano_env\lib\site-packages\theano\gpuarray\__init__.py", line 214, in use
    init_dev(device, preallocate=preallocate)
  File "f:\Projects\Python\Environments\theano_env\lib\site-packages\theano\gpuarray\__init__.py", line 95, in init_dev
    context = pygpu.init(
  File "pygpu\gpuarray.pyx", line 658, in pygpu.gpuarray.init
  File "pygpu\gpuarray.pyx", line 587, in pygpu.gpuarray.pygpu_init
pygpu.gpuarray.GpuArrayException: b'Could not load "nvrtc64_70.dll": The specified module could not be found.\r\n'
```

my cuda version is 9.2 and graphic driver version is 516.94

theano version = 1.0.5

python version = 3.9

pygpu and libgpuarray version = 0.7.6

I've searched on google but there are a few link about this problem and there is no clear solution for it.

in .theanorc file I try to determine the root directory for cuda and determine the "GPUARRAY_CUDA_VERSION" but nothing hasn't changed.

which versions must upgrade or downgrade to another version? and what is that version?

thanks.

Comment: Your question is about Theano and gpuarray, not CUDA. And your problem stems from the fact that Theano development stopped about 6 years ago and nothing has been serouously maintained for at least three. How you setup an old, unsupported theano build isn't a cuda programing question, which is why I removed the tag

Comment: searching `nvrtc64_70.dll` in Google  I found [gpu - Error loading library gpuarray with Theano - Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43577788/error-loading-library-gpuarray-with-theano)

Answer (score 0):

I uninstall cuda 9.2 and install cuda 8.0 and problem has fixed but I don't know for what. The error is about "nvrtc64_70.dll" and cuda 9.2 directory has "nvrtc64_92.dll". Also cuda 8.0 has "nvrtc64_80.dll" but problem has fixed.